# Completing webservice in background state iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any possible way to complete a webservice task when ios application goes to background state using URLSession ? 
I am not trying to upload a huge sized file to the server , instead i am trying to upload a 4 digit key.
i have tried the below method for background task.

```
var bgTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {})
```

For testing purpose , i am calling webservice in a loop and logged. when i go to background mode the webservice calls are getting stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - NSURLSession downloading in background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503164/swift-nsurlsession-downloading-in-background)

Comment: You can also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395810/downloading-in-background-and-waking-app-when-finished/40395988#40395988

Answer (score 1):

**Big upload/download files**

Introduced in iOS 7.

It really depends on how much the task will take time. If it's a big download or upload task (for example downloading a video) you should execute the task using NSURLSession with background configuration. The iOS system will handle the upload/download task. Once the download completes, the downloaded file will be save into a temporary file (so you might need to copy it to another place later on). [Downloading in background and waking app when finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395810/downloading-in-background-and-waking-app-when-finished/40395988#40395988)

**Normal WebServices** (I think that this is what you want)

Introduced in iOS 6

For finite length operation, you can use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler.

```
var task = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler(){}
//do your job (call the service)
//on completion you shouldcall the bellow two lines
UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(task)
task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
```

No need to have configure an NSURLSession with a background configuration.

Comment: yes.. i am looking for the normal webservice. I did the same like you have posted , i made a webservice call loop for checking this scenario . But when the application moves to background it is getting stuck. build settings -> capabilities -> background mode -> background fetch is on

Comment: No need to enable background fetch. You should call the `endBackgroundTask` when you get the result of the web service call. I am telling you again that this should be used only for very fast web services. Can you share your code?

Comment: I would recommend to watch this WWDC video: [background fetch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/204/) There is also another one related to NSURLSession. Both will help you understand how the app will run when it enters background

Answer (score 0):

```
class func generalPost(url: String, postCompleted : (response: String) -> ()) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let dataString = "" 
        request.HTTPBody = dataString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
             let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)                    

             postCompleted(response: strData)                  
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

And you can use

```
 generalPost(url: "http://stackoverflow.com/") { (response) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                UIAlertView(title: "Message", message: response, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok").show()                
            })
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But its not the one that im looking for.The scenario comes when application moves from active state to background state.